# Low side BLDC motor phase current measurement

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, brushless-dc-motor

I'm trying to design a current sense circuit for measuring a phase current in a BLDC motor. Here I'm using the embedded opamp in the STM32G4 MCU. What voltage will be at the output of the opamp here ? and what voltage will be at the non inverting pin of the opamp ? the non inverting input share the same pin with the non inverting pin of the embedded comparator so I want to know to what voltage I will set the treshold of the comparator for overcurrent protection. I designed 2 circuits.
[image: first circuit][image: second circuit]